# Selecting input element with jQuery in CKEditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Okay, this one is driving me crazy - I just don't understand why this is so difficult.

I have created an CKEditor and added my own tab to the images dialogue. In this new tab users can select an image URL from a list.

I would like to set the image url box (a standard input box on the first tab) from this information. Normally I could select this through an ID or class but CKEditor gives every input a different ID each time.

Is there an easy way to select other elements in the dialogue, as reading the stuff here and online just doesn't seem to make sense.

(why couldn't everything just had a nice id like "#image_input_1_1", which would mean the image tab, input 1, CKEditor instance 1, it would be so much easier...)

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I did this:

```
// get current dialog
var dialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
// get the info tab in the dialog
dialog.selectPage('info');
// get the txtUrl element (found id using devtools plugin)
var tUrl = dialog.getContentElement('info', 'txtUrl');
// set this input box to by variable
tUrl.setValue(strLink);
```

I hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: You don't need the dialog.selectPage('info'); and you can simplify the rest with a single call as I suggested.

Comment: I don't understad it because it's available in the API http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.html#setValueOf and in http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/src/plugins_dialog_plugin.js.html it's clear that it's syntactic sugar to perform the getContentElement and setValue in one call

Answer (score 0):

You can do some DOM traversing: Go to the closest common parent and from there decend into the images tab and select the input by classes/tag names.

#### Update:

Alright, here is your traversing, like a little trip around the CKeditor insanely complex DOM tree:

```
$(this)
 .parents("[role=tabpanel]")
 .prevAll("[name=info]")
 .find("label:contains(URL)")
   .next()
     .find("input")
```

Where `this` is some element inside your custom tab.

Comment: Unfornately this is not possible as all the fields have generic names and classes.

Comment: Do you have it accessible online?

Comment: Updated my answer with the traversal that will take you to the promised land.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the default Image dialog, then you can do it this way:

```
dialog.setValueOf( 'info', 'txtUrl', newValue);
```

If you need to use other inputs use the devTools plugin: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Field_Names